# Dynamic page text from dropdown using MS SQL, AJAX, PHP and JSON

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, json

I am stuck. I am creating an event registration. A dropdown value and id are assigned from a sql stored procedure(index.php). When the user selects the event I want to display the event details dynamically using an AJAX call to another page(process_event.php) which returns the details from another sql procedure encoded as JSON and then displays them on the main page. I am able to trace using SQL profiler and can see that indeed the second sql procedure is being requested but the results are not being returned or displayed on the main page.  Here is the  relevant code...

*EDIT: I also should mention that I know the sql stored procedures are producing the desired results, I have tested them using SSMS and flat page queries.*

index.php:

```
        <div id="maincontent">
        <form method="post" action="submitreg.php" id="submitreg">
        Select an Event:

            <select id="selectevent" name="eventid" form="submitreg">
<?php
      $sqlserverName = "SQL2";
      $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"db", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password", "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => 1);
      $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $sqlserverName, $connectionInfo);
          if( $conn )
            {
              $sql1 = "{CALL USP_GET_EVENTS}";
              $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql1);
              if( $stmt1 === false ) {
                  $stmt1response = "There was an error. Please Contact the IT Department";
                  echo $stmt1response;
                  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
              }
          } else {
              $connresponse = "Database Connection could not be established. Please Contact the IT Department";
              echo $connresponse;
              die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
              }
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        echo    '<option value="'.$row['evt_id'].'">'.$row['evt_nm'].'</option>';
        }
        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt1);
        sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
            </select>

        <br /><br />
            <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
            <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" />
        <br /><br />
            <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
        Number of Guests:            
            <select name="guests" form="guests">
                <option value"0">0</option>
                <option value"1">1</option>
                <option value"2">2</option>
                <option value"3">3</option>
                <option value"4">4</option>
                <option value"5">5</option>
                <option value"6">6</option>
                <option value"7">7</option>
                <option value"8">8</option>
                <option value"9">9</option>
                <option value"10">10</option>
            </select>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
        <font style="color:#CED4DF;">All fields are required.</font>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div id="selectdetails">

            Start Date/Time:<span id="star"></span>
            <br />
            End Date/Time:<span id="fini"></span>
            <br />
            Location:<span id="loca"></span>
            <br />
            Other Info:<span id="othe"></span>

            <script src="beans/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                    function insertResults(json){
                        $("#star").val(json["evt_st"]);
                        $("#fini").val(json["evt_ed"]);
                        $("#loca").val(json["evt_loc"]);
                        $("#othe").val(json["evt_oth"]);
                    }
                    function clearForm(){
                        $("#star, #fini, #loca, #othe").val("");
                    }
                    function makeAjaxRequest(eventid){
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { eventid : eventid },
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "process_event.php",
                        success: function(json) {
                                    insertResults(json);
                                 }
                        });
                    }
                    $("#selectevent").on("change", function(){
                        var id = $(this).val();
                        if (id === "0"){
                            clearForm();
                        } else {
                            makeAjaxRequest(id);
                        }
                    });
            </script>
        </div>
```

process_event.php:

```
<?php
    $eventid = $_POST['eventid'];
    $sqlserverName = "SQL2";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"db", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password", "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => 1);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $sqlserverName, $connectionInfo);
        if( $conn ) {
            $sql1 = "{CALL USP_GET_EVENT_INFO}";
            $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql1);
                if( $stmt1 === false ) {
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                }
        } else {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

    $arr = array();
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($eventid == $row['evt_id']){
        $arr = $row;
        break;
    }
}
if ($arr !== null) {
    echo json_encode($arr);

    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt1);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would open up the debugger in your web browser (F12), head to the "Network" tab, then refresh the page and use the drop-down.  There you can see exactly what the browser requests, and exactly what it receives.

If nothing there, go to the "Sources" or "Debugger" tab and put breakpoints in your Javascript, specifically in the makeAjaxRequest and insertResults functions, to make sure they're being called and processing correctly.

To me, it looks like here:

```
$arr = array();
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($eventid == $row['evt_id']){
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
}
```

You're adding `$row` (associative array?) to `$arr` (also an array), but in Javascript you're trying to read `json["evt_*"]` directly.  My guess is you would need to use `json[0]["evt_*"]` instead.

If only one result can be returned, I would just update the PHP:

```
$arr = null;
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($eventid == $row['evt_id']){
        $arr = $row;
        break;
    }
}

if ($arr !== null) {
    echo json_encode($arr);
} else {
    //Send some error message...
}
```

Otherwise you would need to update the Javascript side to handle receiving multiple rows.

EDIT:
Oh yeah!  For displaying on the page, the `.val(...)` function is only good for input-type elements.  For a span you'll want to use either `.text(...)` (data treated as plain text) or `.html(...)` (html tags in the data are processed).

Comment: I made the changes above and you are absolutely right, however it still does not display the results. This is the debug response body: {"evt_id":2,"evt_st":"2014-07-07 15:24:00.000","evt_ed":"2014-07-07 12:24:00.000","evt_loc":"Big Pine, CA","evt_oth":"Give some stuff"} which is what I would expect to see. Is it perhaps something wrong with the function to post back the results to the main page? Is it considered legal to use a span for this?  Thanks Mike!

Comment: Perfect, that was it! You are awesome!